# python absolute import of submodule fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package, python-import

I have seen other posts but did not find answer that worked!

File structure

```
my_package/
      __init__.py -- empty
      test/
              __init__.py -- empty
              test1.py
```

Fail

```
from my_package import test
test.test1
```

gives

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute test
```

Following Passes

```
from my_package.test import test1

# or
import my_package.test.test1
from my_package import test
# now this works
test.tes1

<module 'my_package.test.test1' from ...
```

I have

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import
```

in all files, and using python2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import a package (like `test`), the modules (like `test1`) are not automatically imported (unless perhaps you put some special code to do so in `__init__.py`). This is different from importing a module, where the contents of the module are available in the modules namespace. Compare with the Python standard library's `xml.etree.ElementTree` module:

```
>>> import xml
>>> xml.etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'etree'
>>> from xml import etree
>>> etree.ElementTree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ElementTree'
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> ElementTree.ElementTree
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree'>
```